# Blocked Cors access triggering an ESP32 controller Azure - client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `private`

Tags: javascript, azure, cors, esp32, private-network-access

I am building a web application that will trigger an ESP32 microcontroller.

When I try and do a fetch with no cors - I get this error. The file is hosted on an Azure server. I am unsure if I need to adjust a setting on there - or fix the headers with the cors in my javascript? I am unsure how to fix this bug.

```
1 Access to fetch at 'http://192.168.1.245/update?state=1' from origin 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `private`.
(index):48     GET http://192.168.1.245/update?state=1 net::ERR_FAILED
invokeDevice @ (index):48
myFunction @ (index):18
onclick @ (index):8
(index):48        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at invokeDevice ((index):48:9)
    at myFunction ((index):18:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):8:44)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>start and stop</h1>
<h2>Start and stop the treatment- the device - trigger</h2>

<input id="myIp" type="text" value="192.168.1.245" />
<button onclick="myFunction()"  id="myBtn">OFF</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
        if(btn.innerText=="OFF"){
            btn.innerText="ON";
            console.log("DEVICE IS ON");
            invokeDevice(1);
        }
        else{
            btn.innerText="OFF";
            console.log("DEVICE IS OFF");
            invokeDevice(0);
        }
    }


    function invokeDevice(state){
        console.log("state", state)
        var myIp = document.getElementById("myIp");
        console.log("myIp.value", myIp.value)

        //const url = "http://192.168.1.245/update?state="+state;
        const url = "http://"+myIp.value+"/update?state="+state;

        const options = {
          //headers: {
          //  Authorization: "Bearer 6Q************"
          //},
            headers: {
            //'Accept': 'application/json',
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
            },  
            mode: 'no-cors'
        };

        fetch(url, options)
            .then( res => console.log("res", res) )
          //.then( res => res.json() )
          //.then( data => console.log(data) );

    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```